# Как вычислить длины базисных векторов?

Tags: математика, геометрия, вектор

Всем привет!  Как найти длину базисных векторов в аффинной системе координат? Известно, что есть точки A(1,0),B(0,1),C(3,2). Эти точки образуют треугольник, у которого есть прямой угол с точкой C. CA,CB-катеты. Если вот логически подумать то длина базисного вектора |e1|=|A|, а длина |e2|=|B|. Но я чет сомневаюсь, для чего тогда точка C и все остальное. Хелп плиз.

Условие:
В аффинной системе координат задаются точки треугольника ABC, а именно: A(1,0), B(0,1) и C(3,2). Прямой угол находится у вершины C и имеет катеты |CA|=2, |CB|=3. Определите длины базисных векторов {e1,e2} и углы между ними.

Comment: "Афинская система координат" - это пять :)

Comment: Точно)) Исправил)

Comment: Длины в любом случае можно определить с точностью до множителя... А вот отношение e2 к e1 лежит в пределах от 1 до 3. Данных не хватает (или я все основательно подзабыл за 35 лет...). Приведите-ка точное полное условие задачи, а не пересказ...

Comment: Написал полностью условие задачи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никогда, НИКОГДА, **НИКОГДА** не задавайте неполных вопросов!!!!

Потому что как только вы добавили длины (которые так пренебрежительно послали в первом варианте вопроса в пешее эротическое путешествие), как сразу все в полпинка решилось... Если вы не знаете, как решать задачу и обращаетесь за помощью - ну не усложняйте же жизнь тем, кого спрашиваете! Ну что это за "вам посылка, но я вам ее не отдам"? Не знаете - дайте полную информацию!!

Да, косинус угла между ними - `-2/sqrt(5)` - угол сами посчитаете?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, угол я сам смогу посчитать. А можно я еще попрошу помощи по двум задачам?